How to add an alert on this strategy?
need some help here. tia.
I am not sure what I am doing here, GPT made me do it. I just wanted an alert that is triggered when all 3 values (MAtrendcolor, bartrendcolor, and trendcolor) are red or green.
//@version=2
strategy("Meu Combo Test Alert", shorttitle="combo Test", overlay=true)

// ChartArt's MACD + SMA 200 Strategy
//
// Version 1.0
// Idea by ChartArt on November 30, 2015.
//
// Here is a combination of the MACD with the
// slow moving average SMA 200 as a strategy.
//
// This strategy goes long if the MACD histogram
// and the MACD momentum are both above zero and
// the fast MACD moving average is above the
// slow MACD moving average. As additional long filter
// the recent price has to be above the SMA 200.
// If the inverse logic is true, the strategy
// goes short. For the worst case there is a
// max intraday equity loss of 50% filter.


// Input
source = input(close)
fastLength = input(12, minval=1, title="MACD fast moving average")
slowLength=input(26,minval=1, title="MACD slow moving average")
signalLength=input(9,minval=1, title="MACD signal line moving average")
veryslowLength=input(200,minval=1, title="Very slow moving average")
switch1=input(true, title="Enable Bar Color?")
switch2=input(true, title="Enable Moving Averages?")
switch3=input(true, title="Enable Background Color?")

// Calculation
fastMA = sma(source, fastLength)
slowMA = sma(source, slowLength)
veryslowMA = sma(source, veryslowLength)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
signal = sma(macd, signalLength)
hist = macd - signal

// Colors
MAtrendcolor = change(veryslowMA) > 0 ? green : red
trendcolor = fastMA > slowMA and change(veryslowMA) > 0 and close > slowMA ? green : fastMA < slowMA and change(veryslowMA) < 0 and close < slowMA ? red : blue
bartrendcolor = close > fastMA and close > slowMA and close > veryslowMA and change(slowMA) > 0 ? green : close < fastMA and close < slowMA and close < veryslowMA and change(slowMA) < 0 ? red : blue
backgroundcolor = slowMA > veryslowMA and crossover(hist, 0) and macd > 0 and fastMA > slowMA and close[slowLength] > veryslowMA ? green : slowMA < veryslowMA and crossunder(hist, 0) and macd < 0 and fastMA < slowMA and close[slowLength] < veryslowMA ? red : na
bgcolor(switch3?backgroundcolor:na,transp=80)
barcolor(switch1?bartrendcolor:na)

// Output
F=plot(switch2?fastMA:na,color=trendcolor)
S=plot(switch2?slowMA:na,color=trendcolor,linewidth=2)
V=plot(switch2?veryslowMA:na,color=MAtrendcolor,linewidth=4)
fill(F,V,color=gray)





// Strategy
buyprice = low
sellprice = high
cancelLong = slowMA < veryslowMA
cancelShort = slowMA > veryslowMA

if (cancelLong)
    strategy.cancel("MACDLE")

if crossover(hist, 0) and macd > 0 and fastMA > slowMA and close[slowLength] > veryslowMA 
    strategy.entry("MACDLE", strategy.long, stop=buyprice, comment="Bullish")

if (cancelShort)
    strategy.cancel("MACDSE")

if crossunder(hist, 0) and macd < 0 and fastMA < slowMA and close[slowLength] < veryslowMA 
    strategy.entry("MACDSE", strategy.short, stop=sellprice, comment="Bearish")

maxIdLossPcnt = input(50, "Max Intraday Loss(%)", type=float)
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(maxIdLossPcnt, strategy.percent_of_equity)

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=red, linewidth=2, style=areabr)

// Check if all colors are green
allGreen = (trendcolor == green) and (bartrendcolor == green) and (MAtrendcolor == green)
// Check if all colors are red
allRed = (trendcolor == red) and (bartrendcolor == red) and (MAtrendcolor == red)

// Create alert conditions
alertcondition(allGreen, title='All Green', message='Come to the Green Side')
alertcondition(allRed, title='All Red', message='Come to the Green Side')


I tried a few things that ChatGPT suggested, but I don't know what I am doing here, this is all very confusing.

version 2 is obsolete for many years. convert it to v5
